# Using enumerate for "one-line for loops"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, enumerate

I have a list like

```
my_id = 3

Word IDs: [None, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, None]
```

I want to make a list of all indexes in the above list that their corresponding value is equal to my_id

I want to write a one-line for loop. This is not working. Is there some way to write it as a "one-line for loop"?

My way:

```
list_of_word_ids = [i for enumerate(i,_id) in inputs if _id == id_word ]
```

My desired outputs in this case are

> 4, 5, 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enumerate` returns a tuple with its counter. You can unpack the tuple and check if seconds value is equal to `my_id`

```
Word_IDs= [None, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, None]

list_of_word_ids = [i for i,j in enumerate(Word_IDs) if j == my_id]
```

Comment: You forgot the `in`

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner would be numpy:

```
np.where(np.array(Word_IDs) == 3)[0].tolist()
```

and the result:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```